# Como rotar una onda en Processing?

Tags: java

soy nueva en Processing y necesito girar toda esta onda PI/8 respecto su eje horizontal, he probado con rotate() y translate() pero no se hacerlo porque se me desmonta todo. Alguien me ayuda, por favor? Dejo aquí el código:

```
int xspacing;   
int w;          

float theta ;
float amplitude = 75.0; 
float period = 300;
float dx; 
float[] yvalues;  

void setup() {
 size(600, 400);
 xspacing = width/30;
 period = width/2; 
 w = width+20;  
 dx = (TWO_PI / period) * xspacing;
 yvalues = new float[w/xspacing];
}

void draw() {
  background(255, 255, 255);
  calcWave();
  renderWave();
}

void calcWave() {
 theta += 1/(60/PI);
 float x = theta;
   for (int i = 0; i < yvalues.length; i++) {
      yvalues[i] = sin(x)*amplitude;
      x+=dx;
   }
}

void renderWave() {
 noStroke();
 fill(0, 0, 0);
   for (int x = 0; x < yvalues.length; x++) {
     ellipse(x*xspacing, height/2+yvalues[x], 10, 10);
   }
}
```

Comment: No entiendo lo de girar con respecto al eje horizontal... ¿Quieres decir girar su eje horizontal con respecto al centro de la pantalla?

Comment: Hola @abulafia siento si me explico mal, digamos que ahora la onda se mueve en eje horizontal (aunque las bolas vayan hacia arriba y abajo) lo que necesito es que TODA la onda se mueva/incline por ejemplo 45º.

Comment: Sí, pero el centro de giro es el centro de la pantalla?

Comment: No pone nada en el ejercicio, así que supongo que no tiene por qué

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La instrucción `rotate()` afecta al resto de instrucciones de dibujo que vengan luego, de modo que basta añadirla al principio de tu función `renderWave()`, así por ejemplo:

```
void renderWave() {
 angle=PI/8;
 rotate(-angle);
 noStroke();
 fill(0, 0, 0);
   for (int x = 0; x < yvalues.length; x++) {
     ellipse(x*xspacing, height/2+yvalues[x], 10, 10);
   }
}
```

Con eso ya te sale la onda inclinada, aunque también desplazada porque el giro se hace con respecto al origen de coordenadas, que en tu caso es la esquina superior izquierda de la pantalla.

Si quieres "re-centrarla", tendrás que desplazar el resultado del giro una cantidad que habría que calcular con cuidado. No estoy seguro pero creo que lo siguiente debería funcionar:

```
void renderWave() {
 angle=PI/8;

 rotate(-angle);
 translate(-height/2*cos(angle), height/2*sin(angle));
 noStroke();
 fill(0, 0, 0);
   for (int x = 0; x < yvalues.length; x++) {
     ellipse(x*xspacing, height/2+yvalues[x], 10, 10);
   }
}
```

[image: Resultado]

Comment: Hola @abulafia sale perfecto, muchisimas gracias, solo metia el rotate() dentro del for, lo de translate perfecto. Por último, si quisiera cambiar el angulo a PI/4, tendria que re-centrar con el translate cambiando el valor a multiplicar por ejemplo ir probando 3, 4, etc?

Comment: @LolaBonet Pretendía que mi fórmula con senos y cosenos en el translate sirviera para cualquier ángulo, pero es posible que no esté bien. Siempre te queda el ensayo y error, sí.

Comment: Millones de gracias de verdad! voy a darle al tick y al más uno!